# reading uart in c, garbage only by declaring char array

Tags: c, arrays, uart

I'm reading and writing via Uart, the code is working well, zero garbage. But I declare the next array:

```
        char size_buff[8];
        char width_buff[8];
        char height_buff[8];
        char planes_buff[5];
        char bitsperpixel_buff[8];
        char compression_buff[5];
        char sizeimage_buff[8];
        char xpixelsprmeter_buff[5];
        char ypixelsprmeter_buff[5];
        char colorsused_buff[5];
        char colorsimportant_buff[5];
```

Now I read again by Uart, without making another change and I get garbage in the readings. As a solution I change the size of the arrays and they are left as follows:
            char size_buff[10];
            ...
            char colorsimportant_buff[10];

Now the readings are done correctly, without garbage, but I do not know why it is that just by changing the size of the array of variables that I am not using make the UART read garbage.

Comment: Without sample code we can't help you.

Comment: Sounds like you are triggering undefined behavior somewhere else in your code. When the sizes of your arrays change, you might be triggering different codegen/memory layout/optimizations that make the code work by chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with initialized array with 0 to avoid garbage in first place. You may need to put some code in description if you are getting garbage after UART calls.

```
  char size_buff[8]={0};
  char width_buff[8]={0};
  char height_buff[8]={0};
  ...
```

Comment: It gives the same problem, I repeat, those variables have no interference with the rest of the code, are declared as local variables, and are not used.